# Angular: different configurations per module for a shared module

Tags: angular

I have a shared module, which provides components used by several other modules. Some components need some configuration settings.

The modules using the shared module need to provide different configuration settings for the shared module.

How can a provide module specific configuration settings without forcing each component in that module to provide the configuration?

```
SharedModule:
- ComponentA (which needs some ConfigSettings)    

ModuleB:
   contains several components using ComponentA from SharedModule using ModuleB-specific ConfigSettings

ModuleC:
   contains several components using ComponentA from SharedModule using ModuleC-specific ConfigSettings
```

Is there a way to provide module-specific ConfigSettings for the ComponentA in ModuleB and ModuleC, such that I don't need to provide the ConfigSetting on each component in ModuleB and ModuleC? (I only want to provide the settings once per module).

I tried the following:

- defined an InjectionToken for the ConfigSetting
- provided different versions of ConfigSetting using the InjectionToken on module-level in ModuleB and ModuleC

result: 
- Injecting ConfigSetting in the ComponentA in the SharedModule always gets the same instance (depending which of the modules ModuleB or ModuleC is loaded first)

Answer (score 0):

you can have the configuration in a class and have that class injected in the components that have different configurations. After that, each Module (Module B and Module C in your example) can provide different implementations for this configurations class.

In your shared module you can define an interface for the configuration class and use [Injection Token](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#injectiontoken) in the other modules to provide the implementation for this interface.

Here is a simple example :

```
// Shared Module 

    declarations: [
        MyComponentThatNeedsConfiguration
    ]

// MyComponentThatNeedsConfiguration
    export class MyComponentThatNeedsConfiguration {
        constructor(@Inject(ConfigurationToken) private config : IConfiguration){
        }

    }

// ModuleA :
    providers: [
        { provide: ConfigurationToken, useClass: AConfig }
    ]

// ModuleB :
    providers: [
        { provide: ConfigurationToken, useClass: BConfig }
    ]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, that's exactly what I've already tried (I've  updated my question).

Comment: Ok, to be precise: I tried it with useValue (instead of useClass). I'll try it the way you suggested.

Thanks.